# Violin plot not showing violin curve? Seurat

Tags: r, data-visualization, violin-plot, seurat

I have two conditions showing expression level of a particular gene. The Control condition shows a normal scatter + violin plot, but the MS condition is just a vertical line with scatter. Why doesn't the MS condition show the "violin" distribution? Does this just mean that most of MS are at 0? I am using the Seurat package with VlnPlot()
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We would need a reproducible example to assist. See here <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>.

Comment: @TarJae I have just been following the Seurat tutorial at [link](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html). Then I just used the following to plot a VlnPlot:  `VlnPlot(object, features = "gene.name", group.by = "Condition",  pt.size = 0.1, y.max = 5, adjust=2)`. Sorry if the formatting of this comment is not great

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: MS expression levels can be highly zero inflated in which almost all values are zero. This result in a violin plot looking like a horizontal line at level 0.

Comment: @danloo Thanks, that's what I was thinking as well.